# DTW (Dynamic Time Warping) requires prior normalization?

Tags: time-series

I'm trying [DTW from mlpy](http://mlpy.sourceforge.net/docs/3.4/dtw.html), to check similarity between time series.

Should I normalize the series before processing them with DTW? Or is it somewhat tolerant and I can use the series as they are?

All time series stored in a Pandas Dataframe, each in one column. Size is less than 10k points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DTW often uses a distance between symbols, e.g. a Manhattan distance $(d(x, y) = {\displaystyle |x-y|} $). Whether symbols are samples or features, they might require amplitude (or at least) normalization. Should they? I wish I could answer such a question in all cases. However, you can find some hints in:

- [Dynamic Time Warping and normalization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55083/dynamic-time-warping-and-normalization)
- Section 1.2.1 of [Searching and Mining Trillions of Time Series Subsequences under Dynamic Time Warping](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/SIGKDD_trillion.pdf)
- [Normalization for Dynamic Time Warping](http://luscinia.sourceforge.net/page26/page14/page14.html)

Answer (score 13):

I am glad you asked ;-)

In 99% of cases, you must z-normalize.

Want to know why? I wrote a tutorial on this, page 46
http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mueen/DTW.pdf

Comment: Any easy way to do this z-normalizaiton in Python?

Comment: And, by the way, nice presentation!

Comment: @KcFnMi z-normalization in Python: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.zscore.html

Comment: @eamonn Awesome slides, thanks for sharing your experience, I can't up vote the answer enough

Comment: @eamonn What if the data is multimodal?